# Unable to locate file extconf.rb for ruby 1.8.7 in centos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, centos

I have got require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError) error.To solve this issue i have used following command.

```
yum install ncurses-devel readline-devel
```

To further proceed the following commands

```
ruby extconf.rb
make && make install
```

I need to locate extconf.rb.

EDIT: I  have tried 'find / -name extconf.rb' but no result matches ../ext/readline/extconf.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extconf.rb` is inside the archive of the Ruby library you are trying to compile, in this case  readline. So basically you have to go into wherever the source code of Ruby is stored and issue the commands you mentioned, e.g.

```
$ /usr/local/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0/ext/readline
$ ruby extconf.rb
$ make install
```

Comment: 'ruby -v' shows ruby 1.8.7 (2008-05-31 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux] and 'which ruby' shows /usr/local/bin/ruby but i have nothing in /usr/local/src/

Comment: Well then download the source.

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept and/or upload this answer if it was what you were looking for. Also let me know if stuff works for you!